# How to create a list of external links

Tags: views, 7, paging

I am building an organisational website.
I just came across a situation wherein I need to build a page containing:

1. A list of links (each link has title (linked to a different website) + image)
2. Pager at the bottom

Should I create a view of a new content type that contains these two items? Is there another way to do this? Since the link is to another website, should I take the RSS feed from that site and display content on my site ?

Kindly suggest whether to use a module or not and if not then how to link the title part to another site.

Comment: "Best way to" encourage quarrels, disputes, disagreements. These are hardly ever constructive. Consider rephrasing your question in a way that can be answered objectively, based on facts.

Comment: How will you store single link? In a content type?

Comment: just edited it :)

Comment: Just from those requirements I'd go for a new content type with a link field, and a views page listing this new content type with a pager set.